# Projective chain complex where all but the last homologies are projective

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $C_\bullet$ be an $n$-dimensional projective chain complex, i.e.
$$
0 \to C_n \to C_{n-1} \to \cdots \to C_0 \to 0
$$
is a chain complex where the $C_i$ are projective $R$-modules. Suppose that the homology modules $H_i(C_\bullet)$ (kernel modulo image) are projective $R$-modules for all $0 \le i < n$.

Show that $H_n(C_\bullet)$ is projective.

---

My idea was to consider a short exact sequence of chain complexes $0 \to D_\bullet \to D_\bullet \oplus C_\bullet \to C_\bullet \to 0$ where $D_\bullet \oplus C_\bullet$ is free and the differentials of $D_\bullet$ are all zero. Note that $D_\bullet$ is projective as well. Then in homology we obtain a long exact sequence by the zig-zag lemma
$$
\cdots \to H_n(D_\bullet) = D_n \to D_n \oplus H_n(C_\bullet) \to H_n(C_\bullet) \to \cdots
$$
where all modules but $H_n(C_\bullet)$ are projective. But this seems to lead to nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should not call $C_\bullet$ a *resolution* since this term is reserved for exact complexes.

We want to show $Z_nC=\ker d_n=H_nC$ is projective. It’s a good idea to fit this into an exact sequence, so consider: $$0\to H_n(C)=Z_nX\to C_n\to B_{n-1}C\to0$$

Do we know anything about $B_{n-1}(C)$? Well, there is: $$0\to B_{n-1}C\to Z_{n-1}C\to H_{n-1}C\to0$$And because $H_{n-1}C$ is projective this sequence splits. *If* $Z_{n-1}C$ is also projective then that would imply $B_{n-1}C$ is projective which would imply $H_nC$ is projective as well, since it would be a summand of the projective $C_n$.

So we chase this line of reasoning; there is: $$0\to Z_{n-1}C\to C_{n-1}\to B_{n-2}C\to0$$And to show $Z_{n-1}C$ is projective it suffices to show $B_{n-2}C$ is projective. Then it suffices to show, by the same reasoning, that $Z_{n-2}C$ is projective. And so on… it eventually suffices to show that $B_0C$ is projective, and because there is: $$0\to B_0C\to C_0=Z_0C\to H_0C\to0$$We get what we want.

Comment: Sry, I meant to write *chain complex* and not *resolution* (I will fix this). What I missed  was that direct summands of projective modules are projective, thx.